# Can an attacker mess with a website that doesn't use a back-end server? (and how I can prevent that)

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a React web app where the user can input a .csv of their transaction data, and the app will output useful analysis that will inform their future purchase decisions.

I'm planning to use an input component for the user to input their csv file, then I'll save it in the app's state and use it for analysis

```js
const [csv, setCsv] = useState<FileList | null>();

const handleOnSubmit = () => {
  if (csv) {
    //Convert csv to json
    //Sort and output useful data or something here
  }
};

<input
  type="file"
  name="csv_upload"
  accept=".csv"
  onChange={(e) => {
    setCsv(e.target.files);
  }}
/>

<button type="button" onClick={handleOnSubmit}>
  Analyze
</button>
```

As you can see, this is something I definitely don't wanna mess up because it's dealing with sensitive data. My knowledge of attacks in the web dev world only includes SQL injections and DoS, but that's about it. I'm not planning to use a back-end server for this, so I'm not sure if an attacker can still obtain these sensitive data from the client side unless they get a hold of the user's pc.

I'm also thinking about encrypting the data as well, but I'm not sure how well that's gonna work because the encrypt and decrypt function are gonna be in the same place (there's only the client side, so only 1 place where the code will live in) so it's like locking the door then leaving the key right next to it . . .

Are there any possible attacks an attacker can make on this web app to obtain the user's transaction data? And if so, can you guys suggest some things I can do to prevent that?

Thank you

Comment: This definitely belongs to [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/). There is a good chance that it has been already asked and answered there too.

Comment: Thank you! I'll post one there when my time limit for posting things allows me to make another post :)

Comment: For starters If the website is 100% static and never sends the csv to the server or anywhere, there is little attack surface outside of the user computer (which is outside of your control). Make sure you serve the whole thing over HTTPS (unencrypted HTTP is a big red flag in 2022) and it would be pretty safe from external attackers.

Comment: Yep, I'll probably be hosting this via github pages or heroku, so it's definitely gonna be HTTPS. I'm not gonna send the csv anywhere cuz all the processing and analysis can be done on the client side anyways

Answer (score 0):

Even if the website is static it still needs a server to *serve* the website:

```
client -> gib website pls -> server
client <- ok here you go  <- server
```

Now what if an attacker got into the server and changed something:

```
client -> gib website pls -> server

POSSIBLE EVENTS:
client <- no              <- server
client <- something else  <- server
client <- download virus  <- server (if user clicks download button)
```

A static website isn't immune to attacks; it's only less probable because the attacker has less entry points.

Comment: This makes sense, is there something I can do to prevent this?